# Right way to dynamically update view in Angular

Tags: api, angularjs, model, restangular

What is the right way to updated the Model in the view, say after a successful API POST. I've a textarea, something like in a Twitter, where a user can enter text and post. The entered text must show up soon after it is posted successfully.

How to achieve this? Should I make another call to get the posts separately or is there any other way to do this?

My Code looks like

```
feedsResolve.getFeeds().then(function(feeds){
 $scope.feeds = feeds;
}
```

where feedsResolve is a service returning a promise

```
$scope.postFeed = function(){
    var postObj = Restangular.all('posts');
    postObj.post( $scope.feed.text ).then(function(res){
       //res contains only the new feed id
    })
}
```

How do I update the $scope.feeds in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are posting a new post and that generally posts look like:

```
{
  id: 42,
  text: 'This is my text'
}
```

In this case you can do something like:

```
$scope.postFeed = function(){
    var postObj = Restangular.all('posts');
    var feedText = $scope.feed.text;
    postObj.post( feedText ).then(function(res){
         $scope.feeds.push({ id: res.id, text: feedText});
    })
};
```

A better practice when writing restful service though is to just have your POST return an actual JSON object with the new feed that was added (not just the id). If that were the case you could just add it to your feeds array.

If your JSON object is complex, this practice is the most common an easiest way to handle this without needing extra requests to the server. Since you already are on the server, and you've likely already created the object (in order to be able to insert it into the database), all you have to do is serialize it back out to the HTTP response. This adds little to no overhead and gives the client all the information it needs to effortlessly update.

Comment: Thank you, what if the feed is more complex, like having images, like count, stars etc? Should the response contain all these? How does it work in popular sites like FB, Twitter

Comment: See the last paragraph I added. Yes this is the common pattern in most RESTFUL APIs.